# Minesweeper number of mines java

Tags: java

Hi so I am almost done with this program that creates the class minesweeper game. It compiles and runs perfectly and the game shows up in the GUI client program, but one problem occurs.

When playing, sometimes the a 1 will appear when it has more than 1 adjacent mine, or a 0 when there is actually a mine in one of the eight squares surrounding it. Any help/suggestions are gladly appreciated!

```
private void countAdjacentMines()
{        
    // TO DO: STUDENT CODE HERE
    for (int i = 0; i < mineField.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mineField.length; j++)
        {
            if (!(mineField[i][j].getIsMine()))
            {
                int count = 0;                    
                for (int p = i -1; p <= i + 1; p++)
                {          
                    for (int q = j - 1; q < j + 1; q++)
                    {
                        if (0 <= p && p < mineField.length && 0 <= q && q < mineField.length)
                        {
                            if (mineField[p][q].getIsMine())
                                count++;
                        } // end if
                    } // end for
                } // end for

            mineField[i][j].setAdjacentMines(count);
            } // end if

        } // end for loop rows
    } // end for loop columns
} // end countAdjacentMines
```

Comment: Why are you checking getIsMine() twice? Why are you looping over the entire minefield when you only need to count adjacent mines? This code looks too broken to point out any particular flaw..

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such (this does not exclude your question from being answered).

Comment: You should change your second for loop to `for (int j = 0; j < mineField[i].length; j++)` or something similar, unless you always will have square minefields.

Comment: @Brian: His code looks okay, it's just inefficient. getIsMine is checked twice so that he can skip over nodes that are mines(as that shouldn't have a number). The code looks right, is there a specific number by which it is consistently off?

Comment: Your innermost conditional is nested 7 deep. You're putting yourself in a situation where your code is harder to reason about than it needs to be, so it's no wonder you're confused. Confusing code tends to confuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner loop's conditional is off.

```
for (int q = j - 1; q < j + 1; q++)
```

should be

```
for (int q = j - 1; q <= j + 1; q++)
                      ^^
```

Comment: This looks like it's the problem.